# Alternative to Stack Overflow for tax questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a site similar to Stack Overflow, but for tax-related questions?

Comment: Buy StackExchange...and implement your own!

Comment: The only issue...would be the lack of awesome and benevolent lawyers/tax-pros/attorneys giving free consultation :)

Comment: @Xencor: the net doesn't lack for people willing to give legal advice. :->

Answer (score 8):

Here it is:

http://money.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is there an alternative site to ask questions about corporate taxes? The help page says that "Questions about corporate or government finance" are off-topic for Money SE.